# .NET Core Controller Input always null from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

This is my controller. I have an issue where I am unsure why my Input string is always null. Hope someone can take a look at it and see what my mistake is.

```js
var Name;
$("#AccountCodeName").change(function() {
  Name = $("#AccountCodeName").val();
});

var form_data = {
  "Input": Name,
};

$("#AccountCodeName").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Configuration/AccountCodes/GetAllByName",
      method: "POST",
      data: form_data,
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result)
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAllByName([FromBody]string Input)
{
  JsonResult result = new JsonResult(null);
  result = this.Json(new
  {
      list = accountCodeData.GetAllByName(Input),
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Name is not initialized anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, just added it.

Comment: Try without `[FromBody]`

Comment: Tried that also.

Comment: What plugin are you using for `.autocomplete` ?

Comment: Jquery Autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you only ever set the `form_data.Name` when the page loads. It is never updated. Note that it's not a reference value.

To fix the issues you need to instead create the object you provide to `data` just before you send the AJAX request, like this:

```
$("#AccountCodeName").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Configuration/AccountCodes/GetAllByName",
      method: "POST",
      data: { 
        Input: $("#AccountCodeName").val()
      },
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        // note that you need to call 'response()' here providing the received data
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: If you put `console.log($("#AccountCodeName").val());` in the `source` handler function, what do you get?

Comment: I am able to get the AccountCodeNames value if I put a console.log there. Somehow its not being sent across to my controller

Comment: Try `data: JSON.stringify({ Input: $("#AccountCodeName").val() }),`

Comment: Still null. I tried it with both [FromBody] and without [FromBody]. Both had null

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer

This is how its supposed to be for autocomplete

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetAllByName(string term)
    {
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult(null);
        result = this.Json(new
        {
            list = accountCodeData.GetAllByName(term),
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Jquery

```
 $("#AccountCodeName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            console.log($("#AccountCodeName").val())
            console.log(request.term)
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Configuration/AccountCodes/GetAllByName",
                method: "POST",
                data: request,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result)
            }
        });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using jquery post with .net core post action methods for even models

Here is code snippet that may help you

jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/controller/action',
    data: { Name: $('#name').val()},
    success: function (response) {
        window.location.href = '/';
    }
});
```

.net core back-end

```
[HttpPost, Route("controller/action")]
public async Task<IActionResult> action(string Name)
{

}
```